# How to syncronize <script> tag and Angular .ts file code?

Tags: angular, google-signin

I want to use the Google GSI client in my Angular application. For that, I am using [angularx-social-login](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) package.

The library creates a `<script>` tag on the fly and starts downloading the GSI client (see this [line](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/blob/1c1c2ac745f5e0b316aca1aa28c5ca7bea05f653/projects/lib/src/providers/google-login-provider.ts#L72) and this [issue](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/678)). It does not return a Promise so, how are we sure that when we use the GSI client (through `google` JS object) the script tag has finished downloading?

My question is not that about the library but more generic: in Angular, how do we create a `<script>` tag that downloads a .js file on the fly and syncronize our code in a component .ts file so you can securely access it (in this case, a `google` object that the GSI library seems has itself added for us to the `window` object).

I created this [live project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwsgbn?file=src/main.ts) but I get the error: `Cannot find name "google"`.

Answer (score 0):

`google` is a global object (check `window.google`).

The definition comes from [`@types/google.accounts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.accounts).

Comment: Yes, but I understand that they are just merely type definitions. It doesn't explain how and when the `google` object gets into the `window` object such we are sure that the `<script>` tag has finished downloading.

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the top of your ts script to avoid the error.

```
declare var google: any;
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that solution. But it doesn't explain how and when the `google` object gets into the `window` object such we are sure that the `<script>` tag has finished downloading.

Answer (score 0):

#### **How to be sure that the script source is available and we can safely access it:**

This is only related with how HTML works.

We know that the `<script>` element fires a `load` event when it finishes the download. Then we pass a callback to its `onload` attribute:

```
let scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.onload = onLoadCallback;
```

Inside the function `onLoadCallback`, we can safely use the variables and function exposed by the script (like the `google` object in this case).

*Note:* there is another way to do the same. Check [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#onGoogleLibraryLoad).

#### **How to fix error "Cannot find name google":**

This is a Typescript (TS) error since we are using Angular.

It turns out that the GSI client adds `google` as a property of `window`. With Vanilla JavaScript, doing `window.google;` would work. However, with TS, this errors with message: `Error Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'` because the TS compiler "wasn't prepared" to see this property in the `window` object. A quick fix:

`(window as any).google;  // This works`

Also instead of using `window`, we could simply let know TS that *at some point* a global variable named `google` will exist. As another answer indicated, put this line at the top of your .ts file:

`declare var google: any;`

We could go even further and install `@types/google.accounts` as stated in another answer. Although **this do not provides types as such, but a namespace** (more info [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/64252)).